# What is an acceptable time for a MYsql query to complete?

Tags: php, mysql

I made a logger that shows me all the db queries onscreen. Average is about 30 queries a page. Is that a lot? Each call takes about 0.001 seconds to complete, some longer, some shorter. Here are some totals for a few pages: 0.9 secs, 0.09 secs, 0.8 secs. (Note: these are ONLY the times for the database queries and not image loading etc).

Are these acceptable tiems? What is ideal? What is the industry standard?

Comment: I think this should be on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question is way too broad. The speed of queries used on any single site will vary dramatically depending on what they're responsible for.

Answer (score 3):

If you'd ask me, I would say a page will have to be able to load within 0.5 seconds. Almost 1 second for Queries is way to long.

But, if it is a huge page, which loads of information, a user will probably want to wait for it.

You should probably take a look at the queries, and find out why it takes so long (0.9/0.8)

Add this to your query: `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` and see if any indexes are used.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the query, and the level of interactivity of your application. If you have to provide a web application, you are not going to accept a query that completes in 10 seconds. If you can't avoid it, you may have to use some tricks to make it faster, or to build and return the data progressively as new results are found.

Answer (score 0):

depends on the type of the query and ORM you use